# In text webpart, insert image that does not resize?

Tags: image-rendition, text-webpart

Currently, images that are inserted into a text web part will resize as the window changes width.  I suppose this is a cool feature… until it isn't.  Sometimes, a better web design calls for the content to reflow instead.

Is there any way to stop the resizing?

Or, what would be really nice is to be able to set a minimum (and maximum) size for the image.  But I'm sure that is asking for too much.

Comment: I don't think there is any way/setting available to stop the resizing of images in SharePoint default text web part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

1. Setting a fixed height to prevent it from resizing. Ex.

```
.img-test {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 33.87%;
}
```

2. Use the image as a background and set the `background-position` to `center 0`

Try and let me know if these help.

Comment: My admin has only recently installed Modern Script Editor, which may allow me to set some CSS.  I will try.  I'm not sure how I would put the class on the image.  Do you know good ways to inject CSS into SharePoint?